# How do you transfer a lot of variables to a function in a PHP Script

Tags: php, variables

Okay, I have one.php and two.php, I have a function on two.php but I have my variables on one.php, whats the best way to transfer a lot of variables to two.php?

I used `function($variable1, $variable2, $variable3)'`and for some reason it stopped working after I had 14 or more arguments.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put the variables into an array, then pass the array to the function.

```
$array = array("var1" => "", "var2" => "", "var3" => "");

function process($input) {
  $input['var1'];
  $input['var2'];
  $input['var3'];
}

process($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also put all variables in one.php. just include one.php in two.php. so the variables will be available in two.php and you can use it.

```
   <?php include("one.php"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use php `func_get_args()` for variable number of arguments -

Reference Example -

```
<?php
function foo()
{
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    echo "Number of arguments: $numargs<br />\n";
    if ($numargs >= 2) {
        echo "Second argument is: " . func_get_arg(1) . "<br />\n";
    }
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
        echo "Argument $i is: " . $arg_list[$i] . "<br />\n";
    }
}

foo(1, 2, 3);
?>
```

Source - [func-get-args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php)